# Permission Error

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, chmod, setfacl

I have installed bash shell in windows 10 to run linux commands. I am trying to execute a script which gives error "You do not have permission to edit". I have executed command "chmod 777 script4". Still the script does not execute. Now I am trying to run command "setfacl -m u:harpreet:rwx script4" which gives error "operation not supported". Please help.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please edit your post to include copy-and-pasted console output of the script invocation and error message. Also, if you say you get an error "You don't have permission to edit", but later "Still, the script does not execute". What does the script do? Does it try to edit a file which you are not allowed to edit`? In that case, you would need to change the permissions of that file rather than those of the script. If possible, include the script in your question (redacted where necessary).